# how can i control each button individually in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can i control each button individually in `tkinter`?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Minesweeper:

    def __init__(self,action):
        L=[]
        for i in range(15):
            for j in range(15):
                self.action = Button(win, text = "    h    ",command = self.clickMe)
                self.action.grid(column = i, row = j)


    def clickMe(self):

        self.action.configure(foreground = "red")


def main():
    global win
    win = Tk()
    win.title('Minesweeper')
    game = Minesweeper(win)
    win.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Hi Khaled, good question but can I ask what's currently happening when you click a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is a binding some event to button:

```
from tkinter import *

class Minesweeper:

    def __init__(self, action):
        L=[]
        for i in range(15):
            for j in range(15):
                self.action = Button(win, text="h")
                # bind to button function 'clickMe' that runs while <Button-1> clicked on it
                self.action.bind("<Button-1>", self.clickMe)  
                self.action.grid(column=i, row=j)


    def clickMe(self, event):
        """changes the 'fg' color of the events widget"""
        event.widget.configure(foreground="red")  


def main():
    global win
    win = Tk()
    win.title('Minesweeper')
    game = Minesweeper(win)
    win.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if it included a short description of what you did. Otherwise we have to compare your code line by line and character by character to the original in order to figure out what you changed.